# Software to create a website with payment that is datagrid rather than shopping cart based?

Tags: web-apps

I want to create a website where users pay a monthly fee to use an app based on spreadsheet like editing. I have no idea where to start. The eCommerce ones all seem to be about shopping carts, which I  do not want. My key requirements are: login/pay then editable tabbed spreadsheet like views.

I would like recommendations on software to do this (e.g. a site that gives you such a site out of the box). I am not asking for a how to.

Python-based would be a bonus.

Comment: Would something like Zoho spreadsheets work for you?  See https://www.zoho.com/sheet/

Comment: Thanks, but no. Has to have a front end on it, with paid access for my customers.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll keep my eyes out for you.